Cannot read property 'PluginKey' of undefined when using @toast-ui/editor in JavaScript project
I'm integrating the @toast-ui/editor into my project, which is built with native JavaScript. However, I'm encountering an error preventing the editor from being displayed. The error message I'm getting is:
Cannot read property 'PluginKey' of undefined"

This error occurs specifically within the toastui-editor module. Below is a simplified version of my code:
<div id="editor"></div>

<script src="node_modules/@toast-ui/editor/dist/toastui-editor.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@toast-ui/editor/dist/toastui-editor-viewer.js"></script>

<script>
    const { Editor } = toastui; 
    var editor = new Editor({
        el: document.querySelector("#editor"),
        initialEditType: "markdown",
        previewStyle: "vertical",
        toolbarItems: [['heading', 'bold', 'italic', 'ol', 'ul']],
    });
</script>


I've ensured that the necessary JavaScript files are included, and I'm instantiating the editor as per the documentation. However, I'm still facing this issue.
Note: I prefer not to use CDN links for this library.

This issue was addressed by someone else who preferred to not use a CDN for the library in an issue on the official tui.editor repository. I have copied the relevant portions of the link below for easy reference.

The toast_generator.js file:
import * as Editor from "@toast-ui/editor";

export default Editor;

The webpack.config.js file:
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./build_toastui/toast_generator.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "public", "js"),
    filename: "toastui.js",
    library: {
      name: "toastui",
      type: "var",
      export: "default"
    },
  },
};

The index.html page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/toastui-editor.min.css" />

    <title>Editor</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div id="editor"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="/js/toastui.js"></script>
    <script>
      var editor = new toastui.Editor({
        el: document.querySelector("#editor"),
        initialEditType: "markdown",
        previewStyle: "vertical",
      });

      editor.getMarkdown();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Then run the commands:
$ npx webpack build
$ npm run start

Their final project structure looked similar to the following:
- project root/
    ├ build_toastui/
    │    └ toast_generator.js # temporary script for generating toastui.js
    │
    ├ public/
    │    ├ css/
    │    │    └ toastui-editor.css # css from dist directory
    │    │
    │    ├ js/
    │    │    └ toastui.js # it will be created from webpack
    │    │
    │    └ index.html
    │
    ├ app.js
    ├ package.json
    ├ webpack.config.js
    │


Appreciate your help! I've spotted the issue in the repository. Unfortunately, I'm unable to incorporate the solution into my project as I cannot set up an express server.
